# Ignore common words (the, and) in MySQL REGEXP query

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm trying to query a database of Book titles based on the first letter of the title. However, I want to ignore common words such as "The" and "A".

So when searching for books that start with the letter "T"

```
"The Adventures of Huck Finn" - would NOT be matched
"Transformation of a Runner" - would be matched
```

I'm not very experienced with REGEX, but this is what I have so far (where $first_letter could equal 't')

```
... WHERE title = '^[(a )(the )]*[$first_letter]' ...
```

This successfully matches book titles that start with a particular letter even after the words "A" or "The", but doesn't ignore those words. So if $first_letter='t', it would match BOTH books mentioned above.

I've tried googling it, but haven't found any solutions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you've written isn't valid.  `[]`s are used to denote what is called a *character class*.  Everything you enter between the brackets (with some characters potentially needing to be escaped, such as the literal characters `[` and `]`) is treated as standing-in for a *single* character.

*edit* After re-reading my answer, I realized *lookaround* wasn't a good way to approach this.

The functionality you're groping for is called *negative lookahead*, *negative lookbehind*, or some similar variant.  I'm unsure whether MySQL's regex flavor supports it, but I don't think it would be a good fit for this problem.

Alternatively, you could do a regex that looks like this:

```
^((a|the|of|and) )?[letter of interest]
```

The breakdown:

- There are two groups
- - The inner-most group looks for instances of words you want to ignore
- - The outer-most group just adds a space to the end of that
- The `?` asserts that there could be `0` or `1` instances of this group

You'll have to do the legwork of translating this into MySQL regex syntax yourself.  My apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What you described in the 'breakdown' is exactly what I was trying to do, I just didn't know how to structure that in a regular expression.

This is what I ended up using:
`^((a|the|of|and) )*[letter of intrest]`

Comment: @KevinJantzer I know its a long time, but do you remember how exactly did you achive this? I am stuck at the very same requirement where we want to exclude words like 'the' 'and' etc. Please help?

Comment: @A.Raza - I now use mysql full text search which largely solves my problem. Another approach I've used is when saving the label/title, I also save a secondary version that has the undesired words (an optionally punctuation) stripped.

Answer (score 3):

Read about [MySQL full text search](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304)

Comment: I wish Mysql (or I guess Oracle now) would get off their lazy rumps and add fulltext support to InnoDB tables. Unlikely to happen now, though. Oracle wouldn't want MySQL to get any 'better'.